# Методы ссылаются на разные объекты в экземляре класса python?

Tags: python, классы, методы

Случайно наткнулся на такую вещь:
`goat.show is goat.show` -> `False`
Из за чего python так считает?

```
class Goat:
    def show(self):
        pass

goat = Goat()
print(goat.show is goat.show)
#False
```

Comment: Заметил также, что если сравнивать методы самого класса, то они оказываются идентичными `Goat.show is Goat.show -> True` | p.s. goat = Goat()

Comment: @Iokida Не могли бы Вы привести конкретный пример в коде?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В python метод "создается" при каждом обращении к нему

```
goat.show
```

приблизительно (без учета наследования) соответствует вызову

```
Goat.__dict__['show'].__get__(goat, Goat)
```

```
>>> a = []
>>> f = list.append.__get__(a, list)
>>> f
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7fcf249038c8>
>>> f(1)
>>> a
[1]
```

Выражение `id(goat.show) == id(goat.show)` не гарантированно вернет `True`, и работает примерно по такому алгоритму

```
f1 = goat.show
id1 = id(f1)
del f1

f2 = goat.show
id2 = id(f2)
del f2
result = id1 == id2 # True
del id1
del id2
```

На момент создания `f2`, `f1` уже не существует, и `f2` просто займет то же место в памяти, что занимал `f1`, а значит и тот же `id`. Этого может и не произойти, если между вызовами будет создан какой-нибудь другой объект.

Также это перестанет работать, если убрать из кода `del`

При этом `goat.show is goat.show` работает иначе

```
f1 = goat.show
f2 = goat.show
result = f1 is f2 # False
del f1
del f2
```

> Заметил также, что если сравнивать методы самого класса, то они оказываются идентичными

В случае

```
Goat.show
```

тоже происходит вызов `__get__`, но с другими параметрами

```
Goat.__dict__['show'].__get__(None, Goat)
```

И этот вызов мог бы вернуть произвольный объект, но в случае объекта типа `<class 'function'>` (пользовательские функции и несвязанные методы) он возвращает `self`, ничего не создавая.

А значит

```
Goat.__dict__['show'].__get__(None, Goat) is Goat.__dict__['show'] is Goat.show # True
```

Comment: Не подскажете где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: @MaxU почитайте про [дескрипторы](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). Это относится не только к методам, их используют например геттеры и статические/классовые атрибуты

Comment: @extrn 
Спасибо. Стало немного понятней. Но почему тогда у них одинаковые id при каждом обращении
`print(id(goat.show) == id(goat.show),  id(goat.show) ==  id(goat.show))`-> `True, True`
И что именно сравнивает оператор is, если не id

Comment: Мне кажется дело в реализации функции id, возможно она как-то переопределяет is. Так как также заметил, что `id(100) is id(100) -> False`, тогда как `100 is 100 -> True` (хоть и выдает предупреждение)

Comment: @lokida Возможно это оптимизация компилятора или кеширование. В случае  `id(100) is id(100)` ситуация отличается, потому, что число 100 кешируется, так как попадает в диапазон (-5..256) , а `id(100)`, которое значительно больше (у меня 9082176) - нет

Comment: Немного не понял про кеширование, я имел ввиду странное поведение id вместе с is.

`id(48791546) is id(48791546) #False |
id(10) is id(10) #False |
10 is 10 #True |
58791547 is 58791547 #True`

Comment: @lokida а это уже третий случай - оптимизация компилятора. для одинаковых констант он старается создавать только один объект, если понимает, что константа одна. `print(eval('8791547') is eval('8791547'))` работать уже не будет, а `print(eval('100') is eval('100'))` - будет. по поводу id - обновил ответ

Comment: @lokida Немного запутался в именах, обновил примеры с `is` и `id`, теперь они работают как я описал